# ActionLink + data-loading-text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Pessoal preciso colocar esse data-loading-text neste action link só que não estou conseguindo

**Action Link**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Listar", "Cadastro", new { cadastroId = id, area = "Formulario" }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning", @style = "margin-right: 735px;" })
```

**data-loading-text**

```
<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Carregando"
```

alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só criar a âncora via HTML mesmo.

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Listar", "Cadastro", new { cadastroId = id, area = "Formulario" })" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-right: 735px;">
    <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Carregando
</a>
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZ9Vcj)

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal pesquisei aqui na net e consegui resolver o meu problema

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Listar", "Cadastro", new { cadastroId = id, area = "Formulario" }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning DesabilitarBotao3", data_loading_text = "<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Carregando", @style = "margin-right: 735px;" })
```